# Как сделать что б при клике на кнопку появлялась соответствующая ей картинка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста как сделать при помощи jQuery или Java что б при клике на блок появлялась соответствующая блоку картинка, а та которая была исчезала. Структура HTML должна оставаться такой же. И количество кнопок и картинок может быть любым хоть 7-мь хоть 100.

```css
.section{
  display: flex;
}
.box{
  flex:1 0 300px;
  border:3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.tab{
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.img_item{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
}
.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="section">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="img_item active" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/684/City_of_Zagreb_Croatia_511258.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/111/Lofoten_Norway_Mountains_510947.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/129/Lofoten_Norway_Mountains_511235.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="http://komotoz.ru/photo/priroda/photos/samye_krasivye_mesta/samye_krasivye_mesta_24.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="https://mirpozitiva.ru/uploads/posts/2016-10/medium/1477469507_autumn-panorama.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="http://www.prikol.ru/wp-content/gallery/october-2017/kartinki-04102017-001.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="https://zabavnik.club/wp-content/uploads/kartinki_na_temu_priroda_1_28033417.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="tab">tab1</div>
    <div class="tab">tab2</div>
    <div class="tab">tab3</div>
    <div class="tab">tab4</div>
    <div class="tab">tab5</div>
    <div class="tab">tab6</div>
    <div class="tab">tab7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пара картинок не подгружается, кажется там хотлинк защита

```js
$('.box').on('click', '.tab', function () {
    $(".img_item").hide();    
    var id=$('.box .tab').index(this);    
    $(".img_item").eq(id).show();
    
});
```

```css
.section{
  display: flex;
}
.box{
  flex:1 0 300px;
  border:3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.tab{
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.img_item{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
}
.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="section">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="img_item active" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/684/City_of_Zagreb_Croatia_511258.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/111/Lofoten_Norway_Mountains_510947.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/129/Lofoten_Norway_Mountains_511235.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="http://komotoz.ru/photo/priroda/photos/samye_krasivye_mesta/samye_krasivye_mesta_24.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="https://mirpozitiva.ru/uploads/posts/2016-10/medium/1477469507_autumn-panorama.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="http://www.prikol.ru/wp-content/gallery/october-2017/kartinki-04102017-001.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img_item" src="https://zabavnik.club/wp-content/uploads/kartinki_na_temu_priroda_1_28033417.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="tab">tab1</div>
    <div class="tab">tab2</div>
    <div class="tab">tab3</div>
    <div class="tab">tab4</div>
    <div class="tab">tab5</div>
    <div class="tab">tab6</div>
    <div class="tab">tab7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо